# Python hexidecimal byte interconversion oddity

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, byte

I must be missing something....

```py
np.float32(0xc32).tobytes() # --> `b'\x00 CE'`
struct.pack('<f', 0xc32) # --> `b'\x00 CE'`
```

yet the following doesn't convert back...

```py
np.float32(0xc32).tobytes().hex() # --> '00204345'
struct.pack('<f', 0xc32).hex() # --> '00204345'
```

anyone know the error here?

Comment: What were you *expecting*? Convert back *to what*?

Comment: The error was to use `hex()`, which did something different than you wanted.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hoping to convert from the hex string `0xc32` back to `0xc32`

Comment: Have you tried using `struct.unpack` as inverse of `struct.pack`?

Comment: `0xc32` is not a "hex string". It is an `int` literal that evaluates to a regular `int` object, the fact that this was written using a hexadecimal notation *in the source code* is not really something an `int` object would know.

Comment: @mkrieger1 struct.unpack indeed does work... working on solution that doesn't incorporate my faulty logic. will post when I figure it out

Comment: You *really* must specify your expected result adequately, i.e. the type and value.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, my error was assumption about hex strings... the proper way to conduct this interconversion:

```py
np.frombuffer(np.float32(0xc32).tobytes(), dtype=np.float32)
struct.unpack('<f',struct.pack('<f', 0xc32))
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem there is because thats the hex string of that value. As you convert it as a float, thats the hex representation of that float value.